# How to combine two arrays for form two column data using TCL

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have another question, how would I combine two arrays to form two columns.

I've seen a zip command e.g. 
`set n $a.zip(b)
puts $output $n`

However when I save the file it is all in a single line. Kindly advice.

Comment: The dot syntax is not plain Tcl. You must be using some extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate a zip function with [`lmap`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm):

```
% set a {1 2 3}
% set b {4 5 6}
% lmap x $a y $b {list $x $y}
{1 4} {2 5} {3 6}
% puts [join [lmap x $a y $b {list $x $y}] \n]
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

If you use a Tcl version older than 8.6, then you have to emulate `lmap` itself, like for example shown [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built-in, but it's simple enough to implement:

```
proc zip {var1 var2} {
    upvar 1 $var1 A $var2 B
    set zipped [list]
    foreach elem1 $A elem2 $B {lappend zipped [list $elem1 $elem2]}
    return $zipped
}

set a {A B C}
set b {1 2 3}
set n [zip a b]   ;# ==> {A 1} {B 2} {C 3}
```